# How do I repair a popped button when not at home?

Tags: substitute-tool, clothing

I'm at work and a button pops off of my oxford shirt. I don't have a sewing kit with me (because I'm at work) and I don't want to look like I'm a slob or homeless.

How do I fix the button back on to my shirt in such a way that it will pass a cursory glance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With [twist ties](http://howto.menshealth.com/fix-popped-button-hurry) or wire. In my opinion wire works better.

Using a pinch of glue should hold and crazy glue really works. If it is a light coloured button taking a marker and drawing thread onto it makes it look even more authentic.

---

**Additional Info**

[More inspiration . com](http://www.moreinspiration.com/article/5783/tic-reattach-a-button-without-needle-or-thread) and same link: http://www.moreinspiration.com/article/5783/tic-reattach-a-button-without-needle-or-thread

Comment: Last link 404s.

Answer (score 3):

It just happened to me. Take a small paperclip. Bend it back and forth until you have a long U shape, or you can do this with a heavy pair of scissors. Push the ends of the paperclip through 2 holes in the button all the way until the top of the U lays flat on the top of the button, then push the extended ends through the material of your shirt. Bend the ends back like a staple and you have your temporary fix.

Answer (score 2):

Use clear packaging tape over the button to both hold on the button on and hold the shirt together.

Just be sure to remove the tape *before* it's on too long to prevent residue. Be sure to remove before washing, as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can carry a mini sewing kit along with you wherever you go. Just thread a needle with some thread and then put it in the container that mechanical pencil lead refills are sold in. The container can be stored at work or in your coat pocket, ready for emergency sewing repairs.

Comment: Keep a little sewing kit in your desk. Along with the nail file, aspirin, handkerchief, pocketknife you already have...

Comment: Or ask around, many of the people where you work may carry a sewing kit.